# provider.FileData null in ReadAsMultipartAsync with media files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am uploading files by using HTML File Upload control and passing data to ASP.NET Web API. Everything is working fine when I upload image or any text file or xml file. but it's giving error while I upload media files (mp3, mp4).

My code is,

```
string path = "//My path";
    MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

return await task.ContinueWith<bool>(t =>
                {
                    string originalSavedAt = "";
                    foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                    {
                        originalSavedAt = file.LocalFileName;
                    }
                    return true;
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

In above code, When I upload image file, it show me values in provider. FileData (provider.FileData.count is 1) in foreach loop.
But it is null (provider.FileData.count is 0) when I upload media file.

Status is failure in task lembda expression during media file upload, but status is RanToCompletion during image upload.

Do I need to add anything for media files. ?

Comment: How do you upload them? Have you use Fiddler, or your browser's developer tools to see the difference between the request in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Issue was size of file... Whenever I upload file more then 2 MB. it giving me error.
Need to check in config file (Y)...
Thanks a lot :)